# How to observer when the child is removed from firebase db

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sync data between two devices using Real-time database in Firebase. When I remove the value of a child. I am not getting the observer event(FIRDataEventTypeChildRemoved) for deleting the child.

Tree structure:

```
userID
    folders
        folder_ID1 // to be deleted
            folder_name:"Home"
            folder_key:"folder_ID1"
        folder_ID2
            folder_name:"Home"
            folder_key:"folder_ID2"
```

Now when I delete the child from my first device for the folder "folder_ID1" I get the event on FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged observer but not in FIRDataEventTypeChildRemoved. So I am not able to remove the folder in my second device.

```
[ fdb_ observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot* snapshot)
 {
      // Called with the key "folders" which has only "folder_ID2" after the remove value is called
 }

[ fdb_ observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildRemoved withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot* snapshot)
 {
      // Not called. But if I call removeValue for the child "folders" this observer is called.
 }
```

This is the method I use to remove the child id I want

```
[[[[[[ FIRDatabase database ] reference ]
    child:currentUser_.uid ]
    child:@"folders" ]
    child:@"folder_ID1" ] removeValueWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error, FIRDatabaseReference * _Nonnull ref) {
    NSLog( @"Error %@", error );
}];
```

The remove function is called without any error. But I am not getting the event on the second device. So I am unable to delete the folder in my second device. Also on removing the child_key calls the event for Changed with the snapshot.key "folders". Which has only the folder(folder_ID2) data with it

If I can get the key which I deleted in removed observer I can delete the folder with the key in my second device.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it's like this. But it worked when I changed the way I take the reference.

The reference I set for the remove observer is as below

```
fdb_ = [ [ [ FIRDatabase database ] reference ] child:currentUser_.uid ];
```

And then I changed it to as below code, it worked for me. It now calls the key I remove (folder_ID1) on remove observer. I had to set observer for folders instead one step higher key.

```
FIRDatabaseReference* fdb = [[[[ FIRDatabase database ] reference ]
                               child:currentUser_.uid ]
                              child:@"folders" ];
[ fdb observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildRemoved
             withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot)
 {
     NSLog( @"Remove Folder remove observer %@", snapshot.key );
 }];
```